# Method is calling again and again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am validating a email by making ajax calls to server using rest api, I am able to do this very well, but I want my method to wait till request is either complete or wait 2,3 seconds (whatever standard) is before keep trying...

This is whats happening in code,

```
var regexEmail = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
var $imgEmail = $("#emailValidateImg");
var $txtEmail = $("#txtEmail");
var ValidateEmailClientSide = function () {
    $imgEmail.attr('src', waitImg).show();
    var email = $txtEmail.val();
    console.log(regexEmail.test(email));

    if (email && regexEmail.test(email)) {
        ValidateEmailServerSide();
    }
    else {
        $imgEmail.attr('src', redImg).show();
        $(".form_row").slice(2, 5).show();
    }
};
var ValidateEmailServerSide = function () {
    $.getJSON(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/my/my.svc/Users/Exists/", { email: $txtEmail.val() })
        .done(function (data) {
            $imgEmail.attr('src', greenImg).show();

            var $details = $(".form_row").slice(2, 5).show();
            var emailExists = data.UserExistsResult;
            if (emailExists == 1) {
                $details.hide();
            }
        })
};
$txtEmail.on('keyup keypress blur change paste cut', ValidateEmailClientSide);
```

I want to include above code in timeout,

maybe I can do this,

```
clearTimeout(ValidateEmailClientSide.timeout);
ValidateEmailClientSide.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    // Rest of code goes here
}, 100);
```

**What I want to do**

I want to give user some time before start validation, like 2,3 seconds and if user starts interacting with input again then stop the request and wait 2,3 seconds again before making another request.

Comment: Please provide JSFIDDLE...

Comment: @RayonDabre my web services is not public, so am not sure how can i use that api :(

Comment: You can provide any dummy code..

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a variable, `ajaxRunning`, for example, that would hold the state of the ajax call; `false` - not running, `true` - running. If `false` then call the ajax function otherwise don't. When the ajax call starts running set this to `true` and once it's complete set it to `false`. This should help you make ajax calls only when there's no ajax call running.

```
var $txtEmail = $("#txtEmail");
var ajaxRunning = false; // <<=======
var ValidateEmailClientSide = function () {
    $imgEmail.attr('src', waitImg).show();
    var email = $txtEmail.val();
    console.log(regexEmail.test(email));

    if (email && regexEmail.test(email) && !ajaxRunning) { //<<====
        ValidateEmailServerSide();
    }
    else {
        $imgEmail.attr('src', redImg).show();
        $(".form_row").slice(2, 5).show();
    }
};
var ValidateEmailServerSide = function () {
    ajaxRunning = true; //<<====
    $.getJSON(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/my/my.svc/Users/Exists/", { email: $txtEmail.val() })
        .done(function (data) {
            ajaxRunning = false; //<<<=====
            $imgEmail.attr('src', greenImg).show();

            var $details = $(".form_row").slice(2, 5).show();
            var emailExists = data.UserExistsResult;
            if (emailExists == 1) {
                $details.hide();
            }
        })
};
```

However, if you want the client-side check and the server-side check to be made once the ajax call has completed????, then you want to change your logic to make your checks within the ajax callback. As far as using a timeout is concerned, there is no guarantee that the ajax call will be complete after the set time. The only guarantee is the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `debounce` function:

http://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce

https://lodash.com/docs#debounce

```
var validateEmailServerSide = debounce(function () {
  // …
}, 2000);
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYdqVv?editors=101